# Using PHP/MYSQL book but get no output from PHP when trying to access the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently working my way through "PHP and MySQL Web Development." I've successfully created databases and been able to make tables and use the database. I've also successfully completed all the chapters on PHP and have had no problems with PHP not working up to this point. The goal of this page is return search results from a database. It's a pretty simple thing to do but for some reason nothing is being output from the script to the page. I'm getting no errors or anything. It's just blank with the title at the top. Can anyone please help me out with this? Thank you.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Book-O-Rama Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book-O-Rama Search Results</h1>
<?php
// create short variable names
$searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
$searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);

 if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
 echo 'You have not entered search details.  Please go back and try again.';
 exit;
 }

 if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
 $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
 $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);
 }

 @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'bookorama', 'bookorama123', 'books');

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
 exit;
 }

 $query = "select * from books where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
 $result = $db->query($query);

 $num_results = $result->num_rows;

 echo "<p>Number of books found: ".$num_results."</p>";

 for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
 echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Title: ";
 echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
 echo "</strong><br />Author: ";
 echo stripslashes($row['author']);
 echo "<br />ISBN: ";
 echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
 echo "<br />Price: ";
 echo stripslashes($row['price']);
 echo "</p>";
 }

 $result->free();
 $db->close();

 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: missing code: you need to have a form that will submit this search request so that you land on this page.

Comment: How is the data being submitted? As a side note, don't use `@` it suppresses errors

Comment: The code isn't missing. I just didn't include it as it's a purely an html file and I didn't feel it was necessary. That page isn't the issue.

Comment: Also Paul -- That was used by the book. I didn't use it. But I appreciate the advice.

Comment: post the HTML, there might be a typo or something small. Remove the `@` and see if you get an error

Comment: check my updated answer with fiddle for sample page

Comment: I did remove the @. The error was that class 'myslqi' wasn't found in my directory. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `mysqli` is **not** a silver bullet nor a magic wand!

Comment: You should really learn how to read the documentation, and for example use phpinfo() to see what modules you have installed. You might not have mysqli enabled or even installed.

Comment: @cadavid4j - Do you have MySQLi enabled?

Comment: @Paul nobody said it, but OP thinks it `$query = "select * from books where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";` <-- SQLi waiting to happen

Comment: @Paul I went into the .ini file and enabled it but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You have to restart, and this is a wild guess, apache. No but seriously you have to restart your server.

Comment: I did already restart the server but still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supressing the errors from the line:

```
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'bookorama', 'bookorama123', 'books');
```

Thats what the @ sign does, remove the @ sign and verify that the connection works properly, it might be that your script fails there.

You shouldn't use that, it's not considered good practice as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another php page that sends a post request. Here is a sample one:

Take a look at the fiddle:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Book-O-Rama Search </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book-O-Rama Search</h1>

<form id='uploadform' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='link to your search action php page'>
<legend>Submit form</legend><br/>
<div class='form-inputs'>
    SearchType <input name='searchtype' id='searchtype'/><br>
    SearchTerm <input name='searchterm' id='searchterm'/><br>
    <input type="submit" value= "Search" />
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! There's already a page to submit. I didn't post it just because I know that it's fine. I removed that @ like you said though and I did finally at least get an error. It's saying that class 'mysli' isn't found in my directory. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: mysqli is not installed...check this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: Hey @donaldduck thanks for trying to salvage the answer by moving the code from jsfiddle into a stacksnippet. While that is appreciated, there are legal issues with that kind of edits as explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/578411). It is better left to the OP to make that edit themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me! no white page! If you work with a editor including ftp sometimes saving the file failes. than you get a blank file. in that case safe your code and reopen the file.

as for the sql injection try this:

```
 $searchtypes = array('type1','type2');
 if (!in_array($searchtype,$searchtypes) || $searchterm=='') {
      echo 'You have not entered search details.  Please go back and try again.';
      exit;
 }
```